# Convergence of the integral $ \intop_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor-\frac12}{\ln x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to determine if the integral

$ \intop_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x-\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor-\frac{1}{2}}{\ln x} $
converges, and to determine if its absolute convergence or in condition.

Here's what I tried:

notice that

$ |\intop_{2}^{t}\left(x-\left\lfloor {x}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)dx|\leq|\intop_{2}^{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }\left(x-\left\lfloor {x}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)|+|\intop_{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }^{t}\left(x-\left\lfloor {x}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)|\leq0+1 $

and my explanation for the claim

$ |\intop_{2}^{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }\left(x-\left\lfloor {x}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)|=0 $

is this figure: [image: The total area always remains 0 for natural numbers]

Also, $ \frac{1}{\ln x} $ is monotonic and $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln x}=0 $.

Thus, from Dirichlet's test, the integral converges.

My questions are:

1. How to prove my point (that the red area is always 0 for the natural numbers) in an algebric formal way ?
2. How to determine if this integral is absolute convergent or just in condition ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$$-\frac{1}{8}\leq \int_{0}^{t}\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}\,dx \leq 0$$

and the absolute value of (the fraction part of $x$ minus $\frac{1}{2}$) is a continous function with a positive mean value ($\frac{1}{4}$), hence the integral is convergent by Dirichlet's test but it is not absolutely convergent by summation by parts.

Comment: I dont understand why what you wrote is correxct. Take x=0.9 and {0.9}-0.5>0

Comment: I mean, can you prove that it is not absolute convergent?

Comment: @Waizman: let $f(x)=\left|\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}\right|$. You have $\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx = \frac{t}{4}+O(1)$. Apply integration by parts and profit.

Comment: The *mean value* of a function, if existing, is $$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(t)\,dt$$ I don't which issue is generated by the fact that the fractional part of 0.9, minus 0.5, is positive.